# Drupal 8: Custom permission not working properly

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal 8 and currently trying to create a module for it. However, hours spent, I still cannot make it work.

Following are two files in it:

```
#testmodule.routing.yml
testmodule.testmodule:
  path: '/testmodule'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Index'
    _content:
      '\Drupal\testmodule\Controller\TestModuleController::testmodule'
    requirements:
      _permission: 'access content right away'


#testmodule.permissions.yml
access content right away:
    title: 'Access content'
    description: 'Access content right away.'
```

When I access `/testmodule`, it keeps telling me Access denied. Anyone knows what's wrong with the module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you granted the "access content right away" permission to a role the user you're testing with has?

Comment: @Clive Yes, I granted it in the Permissions view.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with indentation of the routing.yml file. Indentation in yml files are very important. Below is the correctly indented routing.yml file:

```
#testmodule.routing.yml
testmodule.testmodule:
  path: '/testmodule'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Index'
    _content: '\Drupal\testmodule\Controller\TestModuleController::testmodule'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content right away'
```

What is going on is that due to the indentation error, the route requirements (and therefore permission) is not properly parsed, hence the access denied error.

Note that if you don't define the `requirements` and `_permission` (or you misspell them), you get an access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me.

First thing I would like you to try is to go to "admin/people/permissions" and check if "access content right away" permission is granted to the particular role or not.

Answer (score 0):

Also, a good note is to look out for is if the route has an admin path and if so you need to append:

```
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```